# SOLVED! setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build ,stuck on this although the app work normally

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate, stateless

This is my home screen and it is working fine but it is throwing error each time I navigate to it.
I don't know what to do , all of the app is working normally ,  it is just throwing this errors and I want to fix this.

Solution found : added the code block given by Jonathan Ixcayau to my MoviesProvider :

```
@override
  void notifyListeners() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        super.notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }
```

The class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:ronasapp/providers/providers.dart';
import 'package:ronasapp/screens/screens.dart';
import 'package:ronasapp/utils/extensions.dart';
import '../widgets/widgets.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final movieProvider = Provider.of<Movies>(context, listen: false);
    final directorProvider = Provider.of<Directors>(context, listen: false);
    final genreProvider = Provider.of<Genres>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        "Popular directors",
                        style: context.textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 26,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    //directors list
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 140,
                      child: ListView.separated(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: directorProvider.directors.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final director = directorProvider.directors[index];
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                  DirectorDetails.routeName,
                                  arguments: director);
                            },
                            child: DirectorAvatar(
                              director: director,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => const Gap(5)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const WhiteLargeText(text: "Trending"),
                    const Gap(10),
                    //new movies
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: movieProvider.getTrendingMovies(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final data = snapshot.data;
                          return MovieCardsList(movies: data!);
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                        } else {
                          return const Text("Error");
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    const WhiteLargeText(text: "Genres"),
                    const Gap(10),
                    FutureBuilder(
                        future: genreProvider.getGenres(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 110,
                              child: ListView.separated(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  final genre = genreProvider.genres[index];
                                  final moviesInGenre =
                                      movieProvider.getMoviesByGenre(genre.id);
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                          SpecificCategoryScreen.routeName,
                                          arguments: [
                                            genre.name,
                                            moviesInGenre
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      },
                                      child: GenreCard(genre: genre));
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                    const Gap(10),
                                itemCount: genreProvider.genres.length,
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return const Text("Error");
                          }
                        }),

                    const Gap(20),
                    const WhiteLargeText(text: "Coming soon"),
                    const Gap(10),
                    const ComingSoonMovieCard(),
                    // const Gap(70),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error is this : setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I used MediaQuery on another screen , and in the error I saw that it say ,widget builld when calling MediaQuery , but I couldn't find a link to it.

Comment: Generally, that error is because during build, you're trying to change the state that you're building.  You can't do that.  build() needs to be idempotent.  Anything to change the state must happen after build() returns, either with a addPostFrameCallback or a Future.microtask or something like that.

Comment: One of the provider's changenotifier is interfering with a setState call or probably the changenotifiers are interfering with each other. or your FutureBuilders. I can't really see from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which provider is provoking the error, and add this code to that provider

```dart
  @override
  void notifyListeners() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        super.notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }
```